# BackgroundColorSpan is always yellow

Tags: android, background-color, spannablestring

```
textToSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xBFFFC600), o, o + termLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

for some reason the color is always yellow. I have tried two greenish colors :

`0xBFFFC6` and `0x99FF99`

I sense I am messing up somewhere with the order of the colors.

Comment: Try Color.BLUE instead of 0xBFFFC600 and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual solution was to get the color like so:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGreen)
```

I still do not know why it has to be like this.

Comment: This is because `getColor` parses the color value before passing it to `BackgroundColorSpan`. You were passing the raw `hex` value of the color whereas `BackgroundColorSpan` needs an `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the color before giving it to `BackgroundColorSpan`:

```
new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#BFFFC6"))
```